# Entity Framework Core LINQ trouble creating (select case exists) queries

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I'm trying to list all items with an extra column describing whether it's owned by the current user.

So I'm looking for a Linq query that generates something like the following SQL:

```
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN
     EXISTS (
       SELECT NULL FROM OwnedItems
       WHERE OwnedItems.UserId = @UserId AND OwnedItems.ItemId = Items.Id
   )
   THEN 'true'
   ELSE 'false'
   END AS Owned
FROM Items;
```

According to the internet as well as a successful LinqPad experiment this code should work.

```
from item in Items
select new
{
   Owned = OwnedItems.Any(own => own.UserId == userId && own.ItemId == item.Id),
   Item = item
}
```

*In LinqPad this code generates the exact same SQL as I want. But in my project it does something completely different.*

My code is a .Net Core 2.1 project using Entity Framework Core 2.1. Since it is a Core project I can't directly test it in LinqPad as it isn't supported yet.

In my project this code results in an unfiltered SELECT statement querying every Item, then for each of them a separate query to check if it exists in the OwnedItems table. Like this:

1 instance of this query runs:

```
Executed DbCommand (68ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT *
  FROM [Items] AS [item]
```

Followed by hundreds of these queries taking multiple seconds to run:

```
 Executed DbCommand (32ms) [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @_outer_Id='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM [OwnedItems] AS [ownedItems]
          WHERE ([ownedItems].[UserId] = @__userId_0) AND ([ownedItems].[ItemId] = @_outer_Id))
      THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
  END
```

Some further info, maybe it helps:
If I use the same line as part of a where clause, it works perfectly.

```
var q = from item in Items
    where OwnedItems.Any(o => o.UserId == userId && o.ItemId == item.Id)
    select item;
```

The above linq results in this nice sql:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Items] AS [item]
  WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [OwnedItems] AS [o]
      WHERE ([o].[UserId] = @__userId_0) AND ([o].[ItemId] = [item].[Id]))
```

Notes:

- The above code has been mangled manually so there might be typos in there. Please disregard them.
- I understand that this particular query can be done using a left join and checking for nulls but my actual one is more complex and I need (nested) exists clauses.

**UPDATE FOR SOLUTION**

As @KorsG pointed out if the Item isn't materialized, the proper query is generated.
What I found is that not materializing Item works even if I write the following:

```
from item in Items
select new
{
   Owned = OwnedItems.Any(own => own.UserId == userId && own.ItemId == item.Id),
   // Item = item  //THIS LINE GENERATES BAD QUERY
   Item = new Item {
       Id = item.Id,
       Name = item.Name,
       ...
       [Literally every single property listed one by one] = item.CorrespondingProperty
       ...
   }
}
```

So I can actually materialize the full item, I just have to explicitly type every last property. FUN!

Comment: `In my project this code results in an unfiltered SELECT statement querying every Item, then for each of them a separate query to check if it exists in the OwnedItems table.` -- Well that's what your desired query does as well. Can we see the query EF Core 2.1 outputs?

Comment: Not exactly the same. LinqPad runs it in about 0.2 seconds in a single trip to the sql server. In my project the same query takes seconds to run using hundreds of queries.
I included some more code from my projects SQL queries.

Comment: Ah, after you updated your question it's much clearer what you mean. I believe the answer posted will help you solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to enable eager loading for the "OwnedItems" navigation property in the query: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading

Please post your full linq query if I should give an example.

**UPDATE 1**

Seems like subqueries have N+1 problems in EF Core and it will maybe be fixed in version 3.

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10001

**UPDATE 2**

If you don't need to fully materialize "Items" you should be able to do something like this where you create an anoymous object instead which should "trick" EF into what you want:

```
from item in Items
select new
{
   Owned = OwnedItems.Any(own => own.UserId == userId && own.ItemId == item.Id),
   Item = new { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11186

Comment: I'm not using navigation properties here, or at least I'm not sure how would that help. But you might be on the right track, I just don't quite understand.

I updated the question to include a version with the same line in a 'where' clause. That one works. Do you think it might still be an issue with lazy loading?

(by the way the linq posted above is the entire query, i just put a ToList after it to actually run)

Comment: I'm quite surprised, after reading your links I'm still a bit confused but not materializing the Items actually works. I would actually need them fully but I can work around it.
I'm marking this as the answer for now. I'm still hoping that I'm just not loading something eagerly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell EF to load the related data, in this case the *OwnedItems* table.

One way to go about this is to *Include* the related table. If there's a foreign key that links tables it could be easily done like this:

```
var dataWithRelatedData = db_context.Items.Include(x => x.OwnedItems).Select ...
```

Another way to avoid a high number of round trips to the database is to load both datasets in separate queries and then merge them in memory. So you would first make a query to *Items* then with the data returned another query to *OwnedItems* and lastly merge them into a single list of objects. This would do just 2 calls to the database, therefore improving performance.

Comment: The OwnedItems table has the ItemId column which is a Foreign Key to the Items table. There is no link the other way since an item can be owned by multiple users.
So your exact code might not work but I'm trying to load it somehow.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the relation is 1-1, 1-* or *-*, you should be able to include any related data by using *Include* as long as the navigation to the related tables is defined in the EF model

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still struggling with including the Many side in a 1-many relation or if it even makes complete sense.